# How to read each line from a file into list word by word in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read line into a list where each word on that line is different argument. For example when my text file contains:

```
Word1, Word2, Some different words,separated by comma,but no space
Word3, Word4, Some different words,separated by comma,but no space
```

I would like to get lists like that:

```
['Word1', 'Word2', 'Some different words,separated by comma,but no space'],
['Word3', 'Word4', 'Some different words,separated by comma,but no space']
```

Maybe I can even get list like this:

```
['Word1', 'Word2', 'Some different words','separated by comma', 'but no space']
```

So far I've managed to get this work when there is one line in text file by reading each word into list.

```
list_words = f.read().split()
```

It gives me output:

```
['Word1', 'Word2', 'Some different words,separated by comma,but no space']
```

How could I do this when I have multiple lines? Also if I later want to print out first arguments from both lists, can I use list_words[0] and it will give me automatically 'Word1' and 'Word3' ?

I hope this explanation was clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following list comprehension

```
list_words = [i.split(',') for i in f]
```

Comment: Removing `.readlines()` will make this code faster, shorter and also avoid reading the whole file into memory at once (even though the list saves it in memory anyway)

Comment: Thanks @Cyber ! But how can I print first, second etc words from lists I got? For example if I use print list_words[0] I get: 

    ['Word1', 'Word2', ' Some different words','separated by comma','but no space']. But I would like to get only 'Word1'. If I use print list_words[1] I get the second list. Can I do something like list_words[1,1] or list_words[1,[1]] ?

Comment: @user3019389 You would say `print list_words[0][0]` for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split with a comma followed by a space, you could use `re.split`:

```
>>> with open('f.txt') as f:
...   print [re.split(', ',line) for line in f]
...
[['Word1', 'Word2', 'Some different words,separated by comma,but no space\n'],
 ['Word3', 'Word4', 'Some different words,separated by comma,but no space\n']]
```

If you want to split on every comma, just use str.split:

```
>>> with open('f.txt') as f:
...   print [line.split(',') for line in f]
...
[['Word1', ' Word2', ' Some different words', 'separated by comma', 'but no space\n'],
 ['Word3', ' Word4', ' Some different words', 'separated by comma', 'but no space\n']]
```

you can use `strip` to get rid of the `\n`:

```
>>> with open('f.txt') as f:
...   print [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]
...   # or print [re.split(', ',line.strip()) for line in f]
...
[['Word1', ' Word2', ' Some different words', 'separated by comma', 'but no space'],
 ['Word3', ' Word4', ' Some different words', 'separated by comma', 'but no space']]
```

---

In fact, you can also use `line.strip().split(', ')`. I just forgot that you can have a delimiter of more than 1 character…

Comment: im just wondering, in this code why do you need `re.split(', ', line)` instead of `line.split(', ')`

Comment: @jamylak Because every time, I forgot that str.split can take more that one character…